# Issues while using all the attribute for running Neural Network

Tags: r, neural-network

I am trying to run neural network on my data set having 81 variables including dependent variable "AttritionYes", but it is throwing an error saying there is no data argument. Below is the code with the error. Am I using formula incorrectly?

```
> nn1 <- neuralnet(formula = AttritionYes ~ . , data = df.data2[,1:81],
+                  hidden = 9,
+                  err.fct = "sse",
+                  linear.output = FALSE,
+                  lifesign = "full",
+                  lifesign.step = 10,
+                  threshold = 0.1,
+                  stepmax = 2000
+                  ##startweights = startweightsObj
+ )
Error in terms.formula(formula) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `neuralnet` does not recognise the formula in this form, i.e. it cannot expand the dot to all the variables in the dataset.

Try with

```
features = setdiff(names(df.data2[,1:81]), 'AttritionYes')
formula = as.formula(paste('AttritionYes ~', paste(features, collapse = '+')))
```